# How can I make my javascript functions work inside the head tag?

Tags: javascript, html, function

thanks for helping me! Sorry if I worded this wrong or caused you extra time.

I have a set of code, in fact, it is a piece of javascript I learned on W3Schools. The code creates a simple slideshow for my Art.
[Here is the W3Schools Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

I don't like having my javascript code all over my HTML and typically I solve simple issues by using onload events so that all my javascript can stay in the head. I'm still new and genuinely appreciate any insight you have. I want to learn, not have you do it for me.

This is my script, currently, I have to place it at the end of the body tags for it to work. When I place this into an external js file and link that file in the head, it fails as I would expect. My problem is I don't know how to solve placing complex code (i.e more than one function) into the head. Normally on single functions, which is all I have needed so far, I would attach an onload event to that function.

Can someone show me how it is possible to place this set of script in an external file and link it in the head tags?

[Here is my website, I have left it broken in case you want to see the console log errors. The slideshow is down the page halfway and on page load it shows all three images in the slideshow. When you  click the left and right arrows it will change and look normal.](https://austinb.net/austinb.net/welcome.html)

```
<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
</script>
```

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="slides fade">
        <div class="slide-number">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/bballhoop.jpg" alt="Ball Is Life" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">"Ball Is Life"</div>
    </div>

    <div class="slides fade">
        <div class="slide-number">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/portrait.jpg" alt="Portait of Child" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">"Portait of Child"</div>
    </div>

    <div class="slides fade">
        <div class="slide-number">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="images/truckdrawing.jpg" alt="Visions of Old Times" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">"Visions of Old Times"</div>
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>

<div class="dots">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **simply** and **easiest** pure `JavaScript` way is to use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) function which means your `slideshow` function will run once the page is fully loaded and ready so that it will not throw errors.

Just wrap your `slideshow` function like this below and all should be good.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   //DOM is ready 
   console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
   //Run slide show.
  showSlides(slideIndex);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, worked like a charm. I will be able to use this in the future, much help!

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript tries to operate on HTML objects that are not in the DOM yet, it will fail. The trick is to not run your javascript until the page is fully loaded/ready.

Have you tried putting your "active" code inside an event that fires after the DOM is ready?

```js
$(window).on("load", function(){
   showSlides(slideIndex);
});
```

Or if you have jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   showSlides(slideIndex);
});
```

It's a good idea to get in the habit of thinking in terms of the order of execution. I see that you're calling a method that hasn't been "defined" yet. Though this may work in some situation (javascript will "hoist" functions and variables in some contexts) it can still lead to hard to read code and bugs.

I see you're just beginning your journey, so there is a lot yet to discover! Good luck.

Comment: Is there a `jQuery` tag in the question or jQuery code itself ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping good catch, I meant to put in the vanilla version as well and just forgot.

Comment: Thank you for showing me this! Both of these options worked! It seems I was overthinking. Thanks!